# Realm Sync and Subscriptions

Tags: kotlin, realm, mongodb-atlas

From what I understand, Realm is a local database while Atlas is the cloud database. When a Synced Realm is opened, it takes either a partition or some subscription queries that determine what data should be synced from Atlas down to the local realm, and any further changes made to the local realm will be synced back up to Atlas.

My question is, is it possible to query for data that is NOT synced in the local realm but exists in Atlas? For example, lets say Atlas contains user information about UserA and UserB. UserA is synced with my local realm, but I also want to query UserB while not wanting UserB to be synced. Is this possible using in the same realm? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

Keep in mind that Realm can sync both via a Partition strategy where everything in the partition sych's or Flex Sync which provides a more fine-grained sync.

The cool thing is that Realm provides several different ways to interact with your data. As you can see the SDK make a lot of that interaction trivial so you can spend more time coding the UI and less time worrying about end-points and callbacks.

Your app can also interact directly with Atlas using [Atlas App Services](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/app-services/connect-to-app-services-backend/?_ga=2.2621680.1500416540.1667494500-586838695.1657561058) backend which essentially gives direct access to data without syncing.

You can also call [Functions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/app-services/call-a-function/) which is server based code, to gather up data and return it to your app

There's more info at [Query MongoDB - Swift SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/app-services/mongodb-remote-access/)

and for Kotlin, there's the [App Services](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/app-services/overview/)

If you love pinging endpoints directly, you can do that as well with URL Sessions.

Realm provides lots of options - I don't know about your use case but there's often a User partition all users sync with that keeps generally available info about each user - the nice thing there is you can add an observer so if something changes for any user, you're app will know about it.

For example:

A new user signs up and set's their favorite food to Pizza (same as yours) and without lifting a finger you immediately know about that and... pizza party!  (this is an example of relying on events instead of polling)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  For context, I am using the Kotlin SDK. Going back to my "UserA UserB" example, UserA's data is synced and exists in a synced realm that is created using `SyncConfigutation.Builder`. I want to get UserB's data, but since it isn't synced, I would use Atlas App Services like you mentioned. My question is, would it be possible to query the synced realm for UserB's data, which is then fetched via Atlas App Services, or would I have to create a new realm using `AppConfiguration.Builder`?

Comment: About the User partition, I have considered having such a collection with general information about all users, that all users can sync with. My concern is that User information can constantly change, and thus would have to be synced across all devices. Wouldn't this be quite expensive? Or is this actually trivial with Realm

Comment: @spikanor In general, the concepts are the same across SDK's so Kotlin, Swift etc have similar functionality. At a high level, you can retrieve any data from Atlas at any time, as long as you have access; so yes, If user A is sync'ing there data and there's a separate collection for user B, then you can access user B data independently. Syncing across multiple devices and even multiple users is very efficient. Remember that only the *changes* sync, not the entire collection so it's not expensive at all; with the caveat that if the changes included 100mb of images... that can get expensive.

Comment: Ok, awesome! Final question: assuming userA and userB in the same collection, and I have an existing synced realm called userRealm that is subscribed to userA's data only, am I able to query for userB's data in userRealm even though userRealm is not subscribed to userB?

Comment: Hmmm. 'subscribed' could mean a lot of things; is this flex sync? If so, you have granular control over what your subscribed/synced to. At a high level, if you're subscribed to User A's data, then queries can only be run against that data - which is of course the idea; if you're not interested in User B's data, why sync it, right? You could temporarily add a subscription to User B's data and then remove it when done though. Or you could get the data (as mentioned above) via Atlas calls. However, adding a subscription every query doesn't sound like a good idea, user UI experience or $ wise.

Comment: Yeah, originally I meant subscribed through flex sync. Thanks again for the answer, this was what I was unsure about